# Group 'Today's Events' under single Date Header?

Tags: php, parsing, google-calendar-api

I am trying to parse a Google Calendar to use on our TV's to display 'Today's Events'.

While I am most of the way there thanks to the help of a friend, I wanted to see if somebody could help me the rest of the way.

The code below generates the calendar with all the information, but for EVERY entry it shows the date. Since they are all the same day, this is kind of frustrating and confusing when looking at it. I am nowhere near a programmer, but I can make sense of some things.

How would I group all Todays events under a single date heading?

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
    $confirmed = 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.confirmed';
    $three_months_in_seconds = 60 * 60 * 24 * 28 * 3;
    $three_months_ago = date("Y-m-d\Th:i:s", time() - $three_months_in_seconds);
    $three_months_from_today = date("Y-m-d\Th:i:s", time() + $three_months_in_seconds);
    $params = "?orderby=starttime&start-min=" . $three_months_ago . "&start-max=" . $three_months_from_today;
//$params = "?orderby=starttime&start-min=2012-12-01T05:48:47&start-max=2013-05-07T05:48:47&sortorder=a&singleevents=true&futureevents=true";
$params = "?orderby=starttime&sortorder=a&singleevents=true&futureevents=true";
    $feed = "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/REDACTED%40gmail.com/private-REDACTED/full".$params;
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
     if (!$doc->load( $feed )) echo 'failed to load';
    $entries = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "entry" );
    foreach ( $entries as $entry ) {

        $status = $entry->getElementsByTagName( "eventStatus" );
        $eventStatus = $status->item(0)->getAttributeNode("value")->value;

        if ($eventStatus == $confirmed) {
            $titles = $entry->getElementsByTagName( "title" );
            $title = $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;

            $times = $entry->getElementsByTagName( "when" );
            $startTime = $times->item(0)->getAttributeNode("startTime")->value;
            $when = date( "D M j, Y", strtotime( $startTime ) );
            $time = date("g:i A",strtotime($startTime));


            $places = $entry->getElementsByTagName( "where" );
            $where = $places->item(0)->getAttributeNode("valueString")->value;

            print "<div class='row when'>$when</div>";
            echo "<div class='row event'><span class='time'>$time</span><span class='title'>$title</span><span class='where'>$where</span></div>";
//            print $where . "\n";
            print "\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have an answer:

just change this:

```
print "<div class='row when'>$when</div>";
```

to this:

```
if ($old_when!=$when) print "<div class='row when'>$when</div>"; $old_when=$when;
```

and add

```
$old_when = null;
```

before the foreach